# Excel VBA get range of user selected range by mouse

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

This is not the `usedrange` issue.
For example in Excel user selects a range (possibly empty) using mouse, let's say **B4:C12**

And let's say after this without deselecting the range user presses the macro, and macro should tell **B4:C12**.

Can anyone show example?

The macro should be something along the lines of the following:

```
Sub showrng()
    MsgBox SelectedRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Sub macro1()
  MsgBox Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                           RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
End Sub
```

HTH!

Comment: +1 but ReferenceStyle:=xlA1 would match the requirements of the question more closely

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub macro1()
  MsgBox Selection.Address
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim addr as String
    addr = Selection.Address
    msgbox addr

    ' Now, as we found the address, according to that... you can also do other operations

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As selections can include several, independent ranges, the following code shows a more complete solution to the problem:

```
Public Sub SelectionTest()
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String

  Select Case Selection.Areas.Count
  Case 0:
    MsgBox "Nothing selected."
  Case 1:
    MsgBox "Selected range: " & Selection.Areas(1).Address(False, False)
  Case Else
    s = ""
    For Each r In Selection.Areas
      s = s + vbNewLine + r.Address(False, False)
    Next r
    MsgBox "Selected several areas:" & s
  End Select

End Sub
```