# excel vba get range of user selected range by mouse and copy it to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macros. I want to copy the selected range to clip board.

Below is the link where half solution is present, it gives output in popup msg box.

[Excel VBA get range of user selected range by mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686787/excel-vba-get-range-of-user-selected-range-by-mouse)

its like

```
Sub macro1()
  MsgBox Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, _
                           RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
End Sub
```

But if i want to escape the popup and directly copies the result to clipboad????

example: if i have selected the cells from B15 to E40 and F23 cell, it gives the msg as "B15:E40,F23", and i want to copy this msg, not the cell content of these selected cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `Selection.Copy` will place the selected range to clipboard :)

**FOLLOWUP**

To copy the Cell Address of the selected range do this.

```
'~~> Set a reference to Microsoft Forms Object Library
Sub Sample()
    Dim strAddr As String
    Dim MyDataObj As New DataObject

    strAddr = Selection.Address

    '~~> This will put the address string in the Clipboard. To test this
    '~~> After you run this macro, press CTL - V in Notepad.      
    MyDataObj.SetText strAddr        
    MyDataObj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

**MORE FOLLOWUP**

> i want to replace commas with forward slash????

As mentioned in my comment, replace the comma with the Slash.

```
strAddr = Selection.Address
strAddr = Replace(strAddr, ",", "/")
```

Comment: Wrong!!
It copies the cell content, not the output range!
example: if i have selected the cells from B15 to E40 and F23 cell, it gives the msg as "B15:E40,F23", and i want to copy this msg, not the cell content of these selected cells.

Comment: `Wrong!! It copies the cell content, not the output range!` Relax :) There is no need to jump your guns ;) I have updated the above post...

Comment: its gives an error msg as:
"Compile error:
User-defined type not defined"

Comment: It feels like.. you are very near to the solution.. . :)

Comment: Please read the first comment in the code ;) `'~~> Set a reference to Microsoft Forms Object Library`

Comment: i am using ms office 2003 sp3 ... that is missing in reference or i am not able to locate it. how to fix it???

Comment: In VBA Editor, Click on `Tools | References` and then in VBA References Dialog box, Click on Browse and then select the FM20.Dll from the C:\Windows\system32 folder. Alternatively you can add a userform to your vba project which will automatically set a reference to it :) Once done, then run the above code again.

Comment: So were you able to make it run?

Comment: :) Its working 
I have modify it little bit, i have modified "Selection.Address" to  "Selection.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlA1, RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)"
thanks.. .

Comment: just as a curiosity;example i am getting output as "G17:J17,H18:J19,J20:J22,J24:J28,I25,G26:G28,E20:E25,F25,F18,C23:D23
" but if i want to get it like... "G17:J17/H18:J19/J20:J22/J24:J28/I25/G26:G28/E20:E25/F25/F18/C23:D23"
" , i.e. i want to replace commas with forward slash????

Comment: Use the Replace function before copying it to the clipboard. See the updated post. :)

Comment: Done...Done...Done..
Thanks... :)