# Using VBA to prompt user to select cells (possibly on different sheet)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm working in Excel on a VBA project, and want part of my macro to prompt the user to select a range of cells*, which the macro can later do stuff with.

*The type of prompt you get when creating a chart, or using a GUI to insert a function

e.g. here: 
[image: Screengrab showing required functionality - the Excel 'Sum' Function Arguments pop-up]

and here:
[image: Screengrab showing required functionality - the Excel Function Arguments pop-up]

I'm therefor looking for something along the lines of

```
Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox "Please select data range"

    ' allow user to select range (as images above)
    CreateFunctionArgumentsPrompt()    

    'do stuff with user selected range of cells
    ...
End Sub
```

Is it possible to access built-in Excel functionality to perform what I refer to as: `CreateFunctionArgumentsPrompt()`

Note: this is similar to SO question [excel vba get range of user selected range by mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686787/excel-vba-get-range-of-user-selected-range-by-mouse) but differs in that

1. I want to use the built in GUI functionality of Excel as displayed above
2. I need to be able to select and refer to a range on a sheet other than the active worksheet

Comment: I found this link: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/493780-excel-range-choose-button-in-vba-form.html This may be helpful

Answer (score 34):

This isn't using the built in that you showed above, but does allow you to select a range of cells following an income prompt:

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
End Sub
```

This is based on the answer given in [this MrExcel answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/241748-using-excel-built-dialogs-range-selection-dialog.html).

Here is how it looks in use:

[image]

Comment: There is only one problem with this code. The range address that is returned is not fully qualified if the selection is from a different sheet or different workbook. So you will have to take care of that as well :) You might want to see the link that I posted below the question...

Comment: This is awesome! Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Siddharth Rout — I just tested this solution and both `rng.Worksheet.Name` and `rng.Worksheet.Parent.Name` (to check the workbook) returned the sheet and workbook names even when I select a range on a different sheet or workbook.

Comment: Way easier to read `Type:=8` vs `,,,,,,,,8)`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a dialog box (also called a common dialog). Unfortunately you [cannot add one to the existing built in objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837805%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (at least not using VBA).

As mentioned above you can mimic this functionality using InputBox and Forms. That said I have seen proprietary programs that are based on Excel where the company added the type of functionality you describe. However, I believe you have to use C++ or a deeper language to create DLLs that can accomplish this

One thing worth noting about dialogs: Excel has a built in [Common File Dialog object library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which allows you to create common file server dialog boxes (such as Open, Save & Select) using existing Windows API dialogs.